# Tooltips on the badges page need checking

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tooltips

I just hovered over the Gold tag-badge on the badges page and this is what I saw*:

[image: Gold tooltip says 20 questions, not 200]

4 problems:

1. The tooltip says it needs 20 answers. The text says 200. The silver is incorrect too. Other tooltips appear correct in their numbers.
2. Bronze badges have a single `:` all silver and gold badges `::`... That's a bit odd. I'd suggest just one `:`
3. Could we have some title-case for the badge type?
4. What is "score"? Having [just been corrected on our own meta](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7712/how-to-earn-bronze-tag-badge#comment13483_7713) (oh the humanity!) it occurs to be that the language should probably be explicit and say it's talking about a *vote* score.

Taking the above into account, badge tooltips should read like:

```
Gold Badge: Earned at least 1000 net votes....
```

And this seems to be network-wide (which makes sense).

<sub>* Well that's almost what I saw. On my screen there was a mouse-cursor over the badge but KSnapshot is a massive racist** and won't let my cursor be seen by other users because it's white.</sub>

<sub>**Maybe it's just misunderstood.</sub>

Comment: Maybe word it 'Earned at least 1000 net vote points', since upvotes are worth 5 or 10 points, depending on whether it's for answers or questions.

Comment: The text suggests these are only for answers and then do we count accepted votes? I'm not against counting the net vote scores, just that it's made more obvious that's what's being talked about.

Comment: Since the number refers to the score, then it would probably be better to just change 'score' to 'net vote points' or something to that effect. After all, it takes more than one downvote to offset one upvote, so talking about net votes doesn't make sense.

Comment: I'm not following you now... It takes exactly one downvote to offset an upvote when you're talking about net votes... Net votes is just total upvotes minus total downvotes (IMO).

Comment: I hate the word 'net', everything else +1

Comment: Right. When you look at the vote count for a question or answer, that's right. But if the badges are looking at points received/lost due to votes, rather than the votes themselves, then it takes 2.5 or 5 downvotes (depending on if its for a question or an answer) to offset the points for one upvote.

Comment: `void GoldBadge::fixTooltipTypo() {}`

Comment: Error: Unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. is fixed in the next build.  We use a cache view formatter for translation here to make it localizable via roslyn, yet as fast as a `string.Format` after the first run.  The tag score * ratio wasn't being passed down correctly inside the formatting engine...but is now.
2. also fixed
3. we tend to lower case everything, leaving that for the moment
4. that's consistent with how we use score elsewhere

Comment: Thanks for the update, Nick.

Comment: Thanks for [the hat](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/make-it-rain)!