# Inconsistent text on user's tag badge page and on tag badge tooltip

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, tooltips, tag-badges

See these three pages:

- [Bronze C# tag page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/273/c-sharp?userid=22656)
- [Silver C# tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/39/c-sharp?userid=22656)
- [Gold C# tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/40/c-sharp?userid=22656)

[image: tag badges]

All three of them say:

> Earned at least *X* total score for at least **20** answers in the [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) tag.

This same text also appears on the tooltip for the tag badge:

[image: tooltip]
<sup><sup>Also note the double colon after 'gold badge'</sup></sup>

As well as on these pages:

- [Bronze tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=bronze)
- [Silver tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=Tags&filter=silver)
- [Gold tag badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=gold)

[image: tag badges]

But the [badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) clearly states:

> - *Bronze Badge*:  You must have a total score of 100 in at least **20** non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - *Silver Badge*: You must have a total score of 400 in at least **80** non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.
> - *Gold Badge*: You must have a total score of 1000 in at least **200** non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

[image: badges]

**Edit:**

It has been noted in the comments that other users see different numbers in these pages, but in all cases it appears they see the *same* number of answers are required for all tag badge description, regardless of the badge's type.

Comment: I see *Earned at least 1000 total score for at least 200 answers in the c# tag.* and *Earned at least 400 total score for at least 200 answers in the c# tag* respectively. Another [caching ghost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211131/why-is-there-portugese-language-on-meta)?

Comment: I see *Earned at least 1000 total score for at least 80 answers in the c# tag.* and *Earned at least 400 total score for at least 80 answers in the c# tag.* (gold, silver)

Comment: So different people see different counts, *probably* based on the order in which they view the pages..

Comment: I'm pretty sure I checked the gold one first, though.

Comment: @3ventic: Who said *I* checked the gold page first? :-P

Comment: I think [this is a better example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=silver) ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z0mH.png))

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks, I've noted that as well.

Comment: @Martijn no-one did, but it would make sense for the first page to stick its correct value, wouldn't it?

Comment: @3ventic: If this is cached on load-balanced caching servers, and all 3 of us are hitting a *different* caching server, then it could be that the first cache miss determined the count being displayed for the rest of the pages.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I see '200' as the required count on all 5 tabs.

Comment: Descriptions shouldn't be cached in the first place..

Comment: @3ventic: They are adding localisation everywhere, and from [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211131/why-is-there-portugese-language-on-meta) we learn that descriptions *are* being cached separately. The description is variable across languages..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd [screenshot](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10221029/asdfbadges.PNG)

Comment: @3ventic server side cache, used for localization... for each language they have different message so something there got bugged

Comment: It should be just as easy to get the localized string each time as it is getting the cached string each time...

Comment: @MartijnPieters can you please view the HTML source of any page (this one will be as good too) and look for "locale"? For me its value is "en", wonder if yours is different?

Comment: MartijnPieters and 3ventic - I just made on off topic test, did you both get notification of my previous comment?

Comment: @Sha I read it before you edited it (so yes, I got it). It's "en" for me.

Comment: @3ventic hmm... my theory is busted then. Oh well, let's wait for a dev!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: I have 'en' as well, both on Meta and on SO on the stack badges. That value is meant for messages used in JavaScript only, however. And yes, I got notified.

Comment: Regarding double colon, [it's already reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209032/152859).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed and will be out in build `rev 1896` on meta and `rev 1332` network-wide.